# Create Devise user via JSON call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, devise

I am learning how to make and handle api calls with rails. I am using Devise to handle my user authentication/sign_up etc, but seem to be having issues making a post request.

To allow a user to sign_up should i be creating my own registrations controller and inherit from devises? or is there a way to deal with json requests through devises controller?

One example I have seen which would could make the process simpler is

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :json
    def create
      super
    end
end
```

Routes

```
constraints(subdomain: 'api') do
  devise_for :users, path: 'lnf', controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
end
```

So my base url will look like `api.local.dev:3000`.

But with this approach, does this mean I could make a curl request to the following url?

```
 http://api.local.dev:3000/lnf/users/sign_up
```

Answer (score 1):

You should disable CSRF protection and enable JSON response type:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  respond_to :json

end
```

then just call POST request with parameters and format suffix (`.json`)

```
curl -X POST \
  --form "user[email]=user111@example.com" \
  --form "user[password]=password" \
  --form "user[password_confirmation]=password" \
  'http://localhost:3000/users.json'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i thought devise expected its data in the following format `curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"user":{"username":"myusername"}}'  http://api.local.dev:3000/lnf/registrations/create` but i get `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/registrations/create"`

Comment: Use `rake routes` to find correct path to your registration controller and action.

Comment: this is the output of rake routes for this action `user_registration POST   /lnf(.:format)               registrations#create {:subdomain=>"api"}`

Comment: could i ask how you come to that conclusion? what have i missed that I should have been looking at?

Comment: well you where correct, so thanks but would love to know why it works